# How to increase the presicion of text classification with the RBM?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am learning about text classification and I classify with my own corpus with linnear regression as follows:

```
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=7)
classifier.fit(training_matrix, y_train)
prediction = classifier.predict(testing_matrix)
```

I would like to increase the classification report with a Restricted Boltzman Machine that scikit-learn provide, from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html) I read that this could be use to increase the classification recall, f1-score, accuracy, etc. Could anybody help me to increase this is what I tried so far, thanks in advance:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,
                             max_features=None,
                             ngram_range=(1, 1),
                             norm='l2',
                             use_idf=True)


X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_r)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test_r)


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
logistic = LogisticRegression()
rbm= BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)
classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('logistic', logistic)])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to understand the concepts here. RBM can be seen as a powerful clustering algorithm and clustering algorithms are unsupervised, i.e., they don't need labels.
 Perhaps, the best way to use RBM in your problem is, first to train an RBM (which only needs data without labels) and then use the RBM weights to initialize a Neural network. To get a logistic regression in the output, you have to add an output layer with logistic reg. cost function to this neural net and train this neural network. This setting may result in performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that could be wrong.

**1. You haven't properly calibrated the RBM**

Look at the example on the scikit-learn site: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html

In particular, these lines:

```
rbm.learning_rate = 0.06
rbm.n_iter = 20
# More components tend to give better prediction performance, but larger
# fitting time
rbm.n_components = 100
```

You don't set these anywhere. In the example, these are obtained through cross validation using a grid search. You should do the same and try to obtain (close to) optimal parameters for your own problem.

Additionally, you might want to try using cross validation to determine other parameters as well, such as the ngram range (using higher level ngrams as well usually helps, if you can afford the memory and execution time. For some problems, character level ngrams do better than word level) and logistic regression parameters.

**2. You are just unlucky**

There is nothing that says using an RBM in an intermediate step will definitely improve any performance measure. It can, but it's not a rule, it may very well do nothing or very little for your problem. You have to be prepared for this.

It's worth trying because it shouldn't take long to implement, but be prepare to have to look elsewhere.

Also look at the [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) and the [PassiveAggressiveClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html). These *might* improve performance.

Comment: So you suggest me to try with SGDClassifier and PAC?. What parameters do you think are the best for this plus tfidf?. I tried with both classifiers and all my metrics go down. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @johndoe - go down compared to what? I have no idea what parameters work best, that is very problem dependent. You have to tweak them using cross validation or a grid search until you get something that you're happy with.

Comment: compared with other estimators that scikit learn implements. Another thing comes to my mind... Does the feature vector need to be binarized?. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @johndoe - I would say no, you shouldn't binarize it. But i could be wrong, you really have to test and use cross validation to pick what works best.

Comment: But is a beronoulli distribuition, does data need to be binarized?.. I try binarizing tfidf vectorizer and still "works". why not binarize it?. Thanks for the help

Comment: @johndoe - maybe someone with more experience can give a better answer, I was just speaking from experience: for me it worked better without binarizing. If binarization works better for you, I don't see a reason not to do it.